# Should I provide "foreign" language content?

Tags: discussion

In [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/37806/show-off-your-character-sheet-designs), users are invited to share their character sheets creations. I have made one or two, but they are in spanish language, so I don't know if they would be useful to many users.

The question aims to be broader. Is non-english content still considered useful in this site? Or should we restrict to English as our common language?

Answer (score 11):

For *that specific question*, non-English sheets are probably fine. You're going to be presenting and explaining them in English, and much of the value of a sheet is in the visuals and layout, which can be appreciated regardless of the language its labels are in.

In general though, answers and questions need to be written in English, just as a matter of [SE policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13676/do-posts-have-to-be-in-english-on-stack-exchange). For better or worse, English is the *lingua franca* of large parts of the Internet, and that's the part of the Internet that SE is in.

Comment: I do not doubt answers and questions must be on English (I wouldn't be able to enjoy those written in japanese). What about game recommendations and such? Should I recommend a game/adventure that is not in English language?

Comment: I suggest that you should only recommend nonEnglish games if the asker has indicated that they are open to it in the question. (If you happen to know that asker speaks some other language, but they don't put it in the question you should comment asking if they would be interested in recommendations in this other language (that you already know they speak)>

Comment: Yep, clarification to be sure is better than guessing, and start from "no". For example, there is this one RPG I would love to play, and if someone recommended it to me it would suit me wonderfully, but it's in Polish. And I don't read Polish, so I can't play it. :(